# IE6 zoom and filter

Tags: filter, internet-explorer-6, png, zooming

Is there any way to combine zoom property with values different from 1 and filter?
For example, zoom: .5 on block with AlphaImageLoader make transparent areas become black. Assigning background color fix this problem but I need it to be transparent...

Or maybe there is any way to scale with background images in IE6?..

Answer (score 1):

After struggling about two days with this problem, 
I found, that there is several reasons, causing transparent areas on child element become black:

- zoom > 1 or < 1 on parent block;
- position: relative or absolute on parent element;
- negative left or top on child element;
- clip on child element;
- filter on the same element.

I didn't tested much, but in my case applying "filter: alpha(opacity=100);" to parent block helps to get rid of transparency bug.

Maybe this will be useful to somebody...